# Can you infer that $\int_a^b f d\alpha = f(0)$ with no assumptions of continuity on $f$ (but knowing that $f\in \mathcal R(\alpha)$)?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

My problem says

> Let 
>   $$
> \alpha(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> 0, & x\in [-1,0).\\
> \frac 1 2, & x=0.\\
> 1, & x\in (0,1].
> \end{cases}
> $$
>
> Suppose $f\in \mathcal R(\alpha)$. Prove that $\int_{-1}^1fd\alpha=f(0)$.

And so I thought that I could grab any sequence of partitions $P_n$, with $\|P_n\|\to 0$, and that should give me the value of $\int_{-1}^1fd\alpha$.

Thus, I picked $P_n=\{-\frac 1{2n-k},0,\frac 1 {2n-k}: 1\leq k <2n \}$.

Note that $\operatorname{Card}(P_n)=2(2n-1)+1=4n-1$.

Then I calculated  $ S_{P_n}= \sum_{i=1}^{4n-2}f(x_i)(\alpha(x_{i+1})-\alpha(x_i))$: The first  and last $2n-2$ terms are $0$ as $\alpha$ is constant in those intervals, and I'm left with

$$
S_{P_n}=f\left(-\frac {1}{2n-1}\right)\left(\alpha(0)-\alpha\left(-\frac 1{2n-1}\right)\right)+f(0)\left(\alpha\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}\right)-\alpha(0)\right)
$$

If I knew that $f$ was continuous at $0$ then I'd be done, right? As all this would go to $f(0)$, but  I don't have that. How do I go from here?

Comment: @user251257  I thought maybe this could be inferred from $f\in \mathcal R(\alpha)$ but I'm my sure.

Comment: my bad, it might be depending on the points of continuity of $\alpha$.

Comment: you are right, as $f\in\mathcal R(\alpha)$ it follows that the sum converges. So $f(-\frac{1}{2n-1})$ has to converge. In fact, the limit doesn't depends on the choice of $P_n$ ... However I am not sure why the limit is $f(0)$.

Comment: I tried taking the sum $\sum_i f(x_{i+1})(\alpha(x_{i+1})-\alpha(x_i))$ and substracting it from the one above, thinking the difference should go to $0$, but that got me nowhere...

Comment: However, you could just use an other partition. Just omit $0$ and use the midpoint of each subinterval for the function value. In fact, it follows that $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? I think that one way or another I'll have to evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0 } f(x)$ when taking the limit as $\|P_n\|\to 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the partition $P_n = (-1, -1+2h, -1+4h, \dotsc, 1-2h, 1)$ for $h=\frac{1}{2n+1}$. Then, we have
$$ S_{P_n}(f) = f(0)\underbrace{(\alpha(h) - \alpha(-h)) }_{=1} = f(0) \to \int_{-1}^1 f \, d\alpha $$
by assumption.

Comment: You're awesome! Now that I think about it, my partition also worked, I just picked the $t_i$ (the points I plug inside $f$ in the sum) in a wrong manner: I could pick (in the equation I posted) both points to be $0$ (as $0\in [-\frac {1}{2n-1}, 0],[0,\frac {1}{2n-1}]$) and that would've gotten me the result haha.